# Cannot get a person by its id using ms-graph people API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph People API and when I look at the docs [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/person_get) you can get a person by using its id:

I use the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to get people with the following API call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$select=id
```

I successfully get a list of ids.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users...",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$select=id&$skip=10",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "ddb9e9e4-a4cc-46ee-93f4-ba135920c84a"
        },
        {
            "id": "37136f8b-33b3-4596-a63b-d41dc8edda34"
        },
        {
            "id": "8c13d891-bd2f-42e5-8650-450b3318f8e3"
        } 
   ]
}
```

Then I use one of the ids to get more info about a single person by using this call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/ddb9e9e4-a4cc-46ee-93f4-ba135920c84a
```

And I get an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6e138441-5e1d-4f04-a87b-8141547cbb07",
            "date": "2018-05-04T06:36:22"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing sth wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting this error when following Microsoft's documenation.

As a workaround I added a filter.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$filter=id eq 'ddb9e9e4-a4cc-46ee-93f4-ba135920c84a'`

Unfortunately is seems that filtering by id is not supported at this time.

If you have the persons name you can use a filter like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$filter=givenName eq 'Baris'`

At the end of the day I prefer to use /users endpoint to get this type of information.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=id eq 'ddb9e9e4-a4cc-46ee-93f4-ba135920c84a'`

or

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(givenName, 'Baris')`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the persons endpoint is a mix of resources. A person is a mix of mail, contacts and social networks so it can be that the id is an id of a mail contact and not a person. And filtering by name is not unique. I think if such a core feature is not fixed by microsoft for such a long time you can forget this endpoint. I will not use it.

Comment: I completely agree with your last two statements, Microsoft's seeming lack of interest/updates is discouraging. And you're right, `/people` can grab much more personal info than `/users`, which `/users?$filter` is not unique and returns an array of outcomes.